# Android: Current time on TextView has time lag

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a code that shows the current time in the `HH:mm:ss` format. I managed to do so, but there still seems to be a time lag from the system time. The code is implemented in the Fragment, and it is as follows.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm_list, null);

    tvCurrentTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCurrentTime);
    tvCurrentTime.setText("H");
    timeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    return view;
}
Handler timeHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        runClock();
        timeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);
    }
};

private void runClock() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    tvCurrentTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
}
```

The time lag seems to be around 0.5 to 1 second. Here's the screenshot when I run that code.

[image]

Comment: try using TextClock : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you have the lag is due to the timeHandler, as it's not synchronized with the seconds from the system, meaning that your timer can run at various positions in the 0 - 1000 ms. Making the interval smaller will improve the chances to appear correct, but it will not fix it as it depends on when the timer is started.

You can use the [postAtTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) for it on the handler to run at specific periods like 16:02:59:001, 16:03:00:001, ...

Answer (score 0):

Check this code work proper.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm_list, null);

tvCurrentTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCurrentTime);
tvCurrentTime.setText("H");
timeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

return view;
}
Handler timeHandler = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    runClock();
    timeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 500);
}
};
private void runClock() {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
tvCurrentTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE),
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND)));
}
```